# What is the Hibernate equivalent to this MySQL query?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

There are two Models: Page & Tag. One Page can have many Tags.

Page:

```
public class Page {
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue  
    @Column(name="page_id")
    private Integer id; 

    // TAGS
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="pageId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Tag> tag = new HashSet<Tag>();
}
```

Tag:

```
public class Tag {

    // GENERIC FIELDS
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue  
    private Integer id; 

    @Index(name = "tag")
    @Column
    private String tag;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="page_id")
    private Page pageId;
}
```

The task is now to select all Pages which have a specific Tag. With plain MySQL I would do (which works fine):

```
SELECT * from Page join Tag on Page.page_id = Tag.page_id where Tag.tag = 'sport'
```

But Hibernate complains if I do it like that:

```
List<Page> pageList = (List<Page>) session.createQuery("from Page join Tag on Page.page_id = Tag.page_id where Tag.tag = 'sport'").list();
// ERROR: [QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on near line 1, column 27 [from models.Page join Tag on Page.page_id = Tag.page_id where tag = 'sport']]
```

When I delete the "unexpected token" then Hibernate complains again:

```
List<Page> pageList = (List<Page>) session.createQuery("from Page join Tag where tag = 'sport'").list();
[TypeMismatchException: left and right hand sides of a binary logic operator were incompatibile [java.util.Set(models.Page.tag) : string]]
```

Problem with the second approach seems to be, that `Page.tag` is a `Set` and Hibernate seems unable to create it with the result from that query.

So how can I solve this? Is there something wrong with the query or is there a way to solve the `TypeMismatchException`?

BONUS QUESTION:
I found the following solution which somehow works.. a lil bit at least:

```
List<Page> pageList = (List<Page>) session.createQuery("from Page where id in (from Tag where tag = 'sport')").list();
```

It works.. but it only delivers half of the Pages which have the Tag "sport". Can someone explain why?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HQL you simply join using collection name:

```
from Page as page left join tag as tags where tags.tag = 'sport'
```

Your collection tag has a confusing name, I would name it 'tagList' to avoid confusion with the tag property (the String one).

Comment: Thanks, but it still delivers the same error I already got: 
[QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [from models.Page as page join Tag as tags where tags.tag = 'sport']] 

Will investigate more.

Comment: hmm? where's my edit? Winning query was: select p from Page p left join p.tag as t where t.tag = 'sport' ... explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450844/hibernate-org-hibernate-hql-ast-querysyntaxexception-unexpected-token

Comment: The select clause was necessary indeed!

Answer (score 1):

In HQL and JPQL, if you want to refer to entity properties after the FROM clause, you need to assign aliases; so your query would be:

```
from Page p join Tag t on p.id = t.pageId where t.tag = 'sport'
```

there is also an alternative implicit join syntax:

```
from Page p where p.tag.tag = 'sport'
```

To be fully compliant with JPQL, you would also specify the select clause:

```
select p from Page p where p.tag.tag = 'sport'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get errors:

from Page p join Tag t on p.page_id = t.page_id where t.tag = 'sport'

Error: [QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on near line 1, column 31 [from models.Page p join Tag t on p.page_id = t.page_id where t.tag = 'sport']]

from Page p where p.tag.tag = 'sport'

Error: [QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [page0_.page_id.tag] with element property reference [tag] [from models.Page p where p.tag.tag = 'sport']] 

Hmm.. tried everything, still doesn't work. Will investigate more :/

Comment: @Crayl sorry, you have to use the property name, not the column name, fixed in my answer

Comment: Didn't work. Found a working solution. See answer of Julien - But thank you very much for your help!